# Smooth color transition on tab change with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the background of each tab on this tab HTML layout. The transition from when you select one tab to the other needs to be smooth. Right now it changes to white and then to the next color. Is it possible to change it to the color directly using CSS?

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li id="seville"><a href="#tab1">Seville</a></li>
        <li id="alicante"><a href="#tab2">Alicante</a></li>
        <li id="barcelona"><a href="#tab3">Barcelona</a></li>
        <li id="cordoba"><a href="#tab4">Córdoba</a></li>
        <li id="sanjuan"><a href="#tab5">San Juan</a></li>
        <li id="havana"><a href="#tab6">Havana</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div class="tab_container">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">

        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
            <div class="column-left-tabs">

        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
            <div class="column-left-tabs">

        </div>
        <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
            <div class="column-left-tabs">

        </div>
        <div id="tab5" class="tab_content">
            <div class="column-left-tabs">

        </div>
        <div id="tab6" class="tab_content">
            <div class="column-left-tabs">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can view the whole code on this jsfiddle. Test transitioning from the "seville" tab to the "alicante" tab.

https://jsfiddle.net/4yhupgum/

Here is a gif to show the problem: https://gyazo.com/eb7333a156757abacfe1fee8da032dd6

Comment: Add `transition: background .7s;` to `li` element.

Comment: Why do you use .fadeIn() function there? This is the root cause of white blinking effect between the tab changes. .fadeIn() Function is changing the opacity of the element, it becomes white at the beginning and after fadeIn() is finished, it has full color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, it is just showing background-color of body before transforming to other color.
Try resolve it by jquery like below.

1) Get background-color of active tab first

```
var background_color = $(this).css( "background-color" );
```

2) Then apply it to main tab container

```
$('.tab_container').css("background",background_color);
```

this will make your need done.

Check here,

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  //Default Action
  $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
  $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
  $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

  //On Click Event
  $("ul.tabs li").click(function () {
           
            /*code I have added is here*/
            var background_color = $(this).css( "background-color" );
            $('.tab_container').css("background",background_color);
   
          
            $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
   $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
   $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
   var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
      
      $(activeTab).fadeIn('fast'); //Fade in the active content
   return false;
  });

 });
```

```css
.container {
 width: 1300;
 margin: 10px auto;
}

ul.tabs {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 display: flex;
}

ul.tabs li {
 float: left;
 width: 15%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 line-height: 31px;
 margin-bottom: -1px;
 background: #F0F0F0;
 flex: auto;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

ul.tabs li:first-child {
 border-top-left-radius: 8px;
}

ul.tabs li:last-child {
 border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}

ul.tabs li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000;
 display: block;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 padding: 15px;
 outline: none;
 text-align: center;
}
ul.tabs{
  transition:all .1s ease-out;
}
ul.tabs #seville {
 background-color: C95A00
}

ul.tabs #seville.active {
 background-color: E0861A;
}

ul.tabs #alicante {
 background-color: #499540
}

ul.tabs #alicante.active {
 background-color: #7FB438
}

ul.tabs #barcelona {
 background-color: #2744E1
}

ul.tabs #barcelona.active {
 background-color: #0088CA
}

ul.tabs #cordoba {
 background-color: #31124C
}

ul.tabs #cordoba.active {
 background-color: #4D2259
}

ul.tabs #sanjuan {
 background-color: #810012
}

ul.tabs #sanjuan.active {
 background-color: #812921
}

ul.tabs #havana {
 background-color: #C95A00
}

ul.tabs #havana.active {
 background-color: #C95A00
}

html ul.tabs li.active,
html ul.tabs li.active a:hover {
 border-bottom: 0px;
}

.tab_container {
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-top: none;
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 background: #fff;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
 -khtml-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
 -khtml-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.tab_container img {
 float: right;
 position: relative;
}

.tab_content {
 padding: 0 0 10 0;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 height: 365px;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 color: white;
 transition: background 0.5s linear;

}

.tab_content#tab1 {
 background-color: #E67E22;
}

.tab_content#tab2 {
 background-color: #7FB438
}

.tab_content#tab3 {
 background-color: #0088CA
}

.tab_content#tab4 {
 background-color: #4D2259
}

.tab_content#tab5 {
 background-color: #812921
}

.tab_content#tab6 {
 background-color: grey
}

.tab_content h2 {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 2em;
}

.tab_content p {
 font-size: 1.2em;
}

a.tabs-ahead {
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 18px;
 padding: 0.5em 1em;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #D35400;
 border-radius: 0.25em;
 color: #FFF;
 behavior: url('assets/css3pie/1.0.0/PIE.htc');
}

.tab_content h3 a {
 color: #254588;
}

.tab_content img {
 margin: 0 0 0px 0;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 100%;
}

.column-left-tabs {
 float: left;
 width: 49.5%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding-left: 50px;
}

.column-right-tabs {
 float: right;
 width: 49.5%;
}

.column-2-tabs {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 33%;
}

.column-1-tabs {
 float: left;
 width: 33%;
}

.column-3-tabs {
 float: right;
 width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <ul class="tabs">
  <li id="seville"><a href="#tab1">Seville</a></li>
  <li id="alicante"><a href="#tab2">Alicante</a></li>
  <li id="barcelona"><a href="#tab3">Barcelona</a></li>
  <li id="cordoba"><a href="#tab4">Córdoba</a></li>
  <li id="sanjuan"><a href="#tab5">San Juan</a></li>
  <li id="havana"><a href="#tab6">Havana</a></li>

 </ul>
 <div class="tab_container">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
 
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
   <div class="column-left-tabs">

  </div>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
   <div class="column-left-tabs">

  </div>
  <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
   <div class="column-left-tabs">

  </div>
  <div id="tab5" class="tab_content">
   <div class="column-left-tabs">

  </div>
  <div id="tab6" class="tab_content">
   <div class="column-left-tabs">

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you for the answer and detailed description.

Comment: Is there a way to change the length of the transition?

Comment: Yes, you can do it using `transition-duration` property. 
eg.  `transition-duration: 5s;`

Comment: Or else, you can make fadeIn slow.  `$(activeTab).fadeIn('slow');`

Answer (score 1):

In every `.tab_content` div you have an other div `<div class="column-left-tabs">`   and you are not closing it in any `.tab_content` div.

This is your mistake. check it and replace `<div class="column-left-tabs">` with `<div class="column-left-tabs"></div>`. That's it.

```
    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">

    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
        <div class="column-left-tabs">

    </div>
</div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
        <div class="column-left-tabs">

    </div>
</div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
        <div class="column-left-tabs">

    </div>
</div>
    <div id="tab5" class="tab_content">
        <div class="column-left-tabs">

    </div>
</div>
    <div id="tab6" class="tab_content">
        <div class="column-left-tabs">

    </div>
</div>
```

Replace Your CSS with this code:

```
    .container {
    width: 1300;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

ul.tabs {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
}

ul.tabs li {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 31px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    background: #F0F0F0;
    flex: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

ul.tabs li:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
}

ul.tabs li:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}

ul.tabs li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 15px;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.tabs #seville {
    background-color: C95A00
}

ul.tabs #seville.active {
    background-color: E0861A;
}

ul.tabs #alicante {
    background-color: #499540
}

ul.tabs #alicante.active {
    background-color: #7FB438
}

ul.tabs #barcelona {
    background-color: #2744E1
}

ul.tabs #barcelona.active {
    background-color: #0088CA
}

ul.tabs #cordoba {
    background-color: #31124C
}

ul.tabs #cordoba.active {
    background-color: #4D2259
}

ul.tabs #sanjuan {
    background-color: #810012
}

ul.tabs #sanjuan.active {
    background-color: #812921
}

ul.tabs #havana {
    background-color: #C95A00
}

ul.tabs #havana.active {
    background-color: #C95A00
}

html ul.tabs li.active,
html ul.tabs li.active a:hover {
    border-bottom: 0px;
}

.tab_container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-top: none;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.tab_container img {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

.tab_content {
    padding: 0 0 10 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    height: 365px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    transition: background 0.5s linear;

}

.tab_content#tab1 {
    background-color: E0861A;
}

.tab_content#tab2 {
    background-color: #7FB438
}

.tab_content#tab3 {
    background-color: #0088CA
}

.tab_content#tab4 {
    background-color: #4D2259
}

.tab_content#tab5 {
    background-color: #812921
}

.tab_content#tab6 {
    background-color: #C95A00
}

.tab_content h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.tab_content p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

a.tabs-ahead {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #D35400;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    color: #FFF;
    behavior: url('assets/css3pie/1.0.0/PIE.htc');
}

.tab_content h3 a {
    color: #254588;
}

.tab_content img {
    margin: 0 0 0px 0;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

.column-left-tabs {
    float: left;
    width: 49.5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

.column-right-tabs {
    float: right;
    width: 49.5%;
}

.column-2-tabs {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
}

.column-1-tabs {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}

.column-3-tabs {
    float: right;
    width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about first and last tabs?

Comment: See new edited answer and make changes. I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Yea, I just realized that. That was from copying my code and trying to remove the useless inner stuff. However, when I remove the extra div on the jsfiddle the problem persists. https://jsfiddle.net/4yhupgum/7/

Comment: After removing `<div class="column-left-tabs"></div>` this div, code is running fine. What div should remove you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking out for this

```
ul.tabs {
  transition:all .8s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried this already and it changes to white before it changes to the other color. Here is a gif to represent it: https://gyazo.com/eb7333a156757abacfe1fee8da032dd6

Comment: As the default background is white this will appear once the background is changed

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really change to white though. You're just seeing the background. The problem is that you have several windows, corresponding to your tabs. So when you display one of them the previous one is hidden right away (so you don't really see it's color anymore), and the new one is placed and it goes from the default `transparent` to the color you chose.

What I advise is having a single `.page-wrapper` element, and place all pages in that. Then give it a `transition: background-color .8s` and while you're hiding and showing the pages within it, change the `.page-wrapper`'s background-color property.